# Random JavaScript Errors in CRM 2011 Outlook Client

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

We are receiving some JavaScript errors that are happening in the Outlook Client only.  They are sporadic, and difficult to reproduce.  They tend to come from the Order form.  Examples include:

- "Can't execute code from a freed script..." from the Address Lookup on the Order
- "this.$B_1' is null or not an object" from "_static/_controls/ribbon/ribbon.js" (trying to run a report)

Has anyone seen these issues or have a good way to troubleshoot?

Comment: I have seen - they are the bane of my life! But only through the web UI, not the Outlook client. No idea where they are coming from or how to resolve. We have lots of scripts running on form load so have always assumed it is a clash there, but never proven it either way.

Comment: Did you ever track this one down?

Comment: @glosrob If that occurs in the on-line (or even better on-premise) version, you can always trace/debug. And it could prove very valuable to those who only can reproduce the issue in the client for Outlook, as they are sitting ducks with no means to debug. :)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your JavaScript.  I've seen this in upgrades mostly.  Unfortunately it is painful to troubleshoot.  If you are using setTimout, look at that code first.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I am using setTimeout in a couple of places. I'll take a look at that code to see if it could be causing some of these problems.