# Layout problems in CRM for Outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

I just realized that what is a nice and working layout of a form with a webresource in on-line version, looses some (but not all) of the formatting when accessed via Outlook. It looks ugly and, I also get errors.

It's somehow related to the JavaScript added to the solution. Or, rather, the web resources, I'd say. Any suggestions on how to debug? F12 doesn't show the console when run from Outlook. I haven't done much with that version so any hint might be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the page you see in the CRM-Outlook is indeed rendered by IE, it's being served from another version of the engine than what is used to browse. During the rendition process it's "*picturized*" (lacking a better word for it) so what you see originates in a webpage but isn't one.

I don't think there's a way to debug **that** version. You can only rely that the development you've tested will work as supposed to. Note that there's no connected process of IE run at the same time as the Outlook client.

I'll gladly stand corrected but as far I've tried (and I've tried a lot, **a lot**), there's no way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to narrow down your problem to a part of the script? Could you for instance disable and enable parts of the script(s) to see what works and what does not?

Since the layout is also being influenced, I think you are doing some (or a lot of?) DOM manipulation. [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx) states:

> HTML DOM manipulation is not supported

But there should not be that much of a problem (heard that one before...) using Outlook: [Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook client and browser rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518636/dynamics-crm-2011-outlook-client-and-browser-rendering)

Edit:
Just to prevent people overlooking the link to a related post from the comments: [Random JavaScript Errors in CRM 2011 Outlook Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128333/random-javascript-errors-in-crm-2011-outlook-client)

Comment: So, no debug possibility? By the way, I'm only using supported DOM manipulation. Id est, I put in a web resource and in that IFRAME, I'm doing all my magic. The solution requires me to do stuff that's not really allowed (or even possible) in the on-line version. By other words, I'm required to use that approach to satisfy the needs of the customer.

Comment: No, I do not know of a debug possibility other than reducing the scripts and see at what part things go wrong. Already saw this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128333/random-javascript-errors-in-crm-2011-outlook-client

Comment: Now I have. Thanks for the pointer. Me not like. Me not like at all.